# Android source code application start time logging

Tags: android, android-source

I am working on my thesis and i need to develop an android extension for Android-Source 4.1.1.
In my part of task, i need to log the application starting time in form of a txt or xml file.
This file is sent with an already existing extension to the cloud, but i will not go into detail now.

I need to edit some of Android system classes in android source code and my question is now, how can I get the app start time, without using an app?
Which classes / methods are called when an app is started? I must implement the timeStamp-Method in the right place.
I was thinking to edit the class Activity.java to detect the starting time in the onStart()-Method whenever the onStart() method is invoked.
But maybe the method is not only invoked for normal apps, it is also started for system applications.

Greetings,

Comment: These are already logged as part of event logs, may be you just need to parse them]

Comment: Can you give me pls more detail information. I need the currentTimeMillis().

Answer (score 0):

Edit onCreate() method of Activity.java

Take a look at this android activity lifecycle. onCreate() method is called whenever activity is launched, so you can edit this method.

[image: Android Activiy life cycle]